# Firebase Authentication ReferenceError: Can't find variable: auth

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

ReferenceError: Can't find variable: auth

please help

```
const handleLogin = () => {
    auth
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(userCredentials => {
        const user = userCredentials.user;
        console.log('Logged in with:', user.email);
      })
      .catch(error => alert(error.message))
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install firebase/auth package
and import auth package in the component where it used
for details, refer to this link https://rnfirebase.io/auth/usage

and it should be like this
`auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)`

Answer (score 1):

Install `@react-native-firebase/auth` from

`npm install @react-native-firebase/auth`

and import

`import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth'`

Answer (score 0):

Where do you expect `auth` to come from?

If you're following the Firebase documentation, the [getting started](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start) page initialized an `auth` variable as:

```
// Initialize Firebase Authentication and get a reference to the service
const auth = firebase.auth();
```